How to Implement Data-Bound Format Pane Option Using Selection IDs for Table DataView Mapping?
I want to implement a data-bound format pane option using selection IDs generated with withTable(table: DataViewTable, rowIndex: number). However, the DataView object does not include dynamic objects when I use the selection ids generated using withTable.

As a workaround, I attempted to use categorical DataView mapping. However, the "Do Not Summarize" option does not return any values array; it only returns the categories.
